# yajra DataTable with join not working in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

relation of customer with job

```js
 public function customer() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Customer','customerid');
    }

  public function jobs(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Job','customerid');
    }
```

in controller

```js
protected  function getJobs(){
   $jobs = Job::Join('customer','jobs.customerid','=','customer.id')
            ->select(array('jobs.id','customer.firstname','customer.lastname','jobs.jobstatus','jobs.trialdate','jobs.deliverydate')); 
        return Datatables::of($jobs)
            ->addColumn('action', '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" href="{{ URL::to(\'updatejob/\'.$id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>')
            ->make();
   
    }
```

it throw following error

```js
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `jobs`.`id`, `customer`.`firstname`, `customer`.`lastname`, `jobs`.`jobstatus`, `jobs`.`trialdate`, `jobs`.`deliverydate` from `jobs` inner join `customer` on `jobs`.`customerid` = `customer`.`id` order by `0` asc limit 10 offset 0)
```

i'm stuck in this  issue from 2 day please help me to get out from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply update the composer ->php composer.phar update 
Its working fine now 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed "order by" in your query, try this :

```
protected  function getJobs(){
        $jobs = Job::Join('customer','jobs.customerid','=','customer.id')
            ->select(array('jobs.id','customer.firstname','customer.lastname','jobs.jobstatus','jobs.trialdate','jobs.deliverydate'))
            ->orderBy('customer.lastname')->get();  
        return Datatables::of($jobs)
            ->addColumn('action', '<a class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit" href="{{ URL::to(\'updatejob/\'.$id) }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>')
        ->make();

}
```